# Custom partiotioning of JavaDStreamPairRDD

Tags: spark-streaming

In Spark streaming, what's the recommended way to implement a custom partiotioner on DStreams?

I've used the JavaPairRDD.partitionBy(Partitioner) in batch mode but haven't found an equivalent on JavaDStreamPairRDD.

Thanks

Comment: what would be the use case for the partitioner?

Answer (score 1):

Partitions on DStreams are created by the process of getting data from the receiver. The data stream created by each receiver is cut in micro batches of size `spark.streaming.blockInterval` (200ms by default) each micro batch becomes a partition on the RDD produced for the streaming interval.
Hence, the streaming partitioning is a consequence of micro batching and custom partitioner wouldn't make sense at this level.

If you need those partitions in a certain custom shape, you could repartition each RDD of the DStream:

```
dstream.foreachRDD{rdd => 
val repRDD = rdd.partitionBy(...)
... do stuff ...
}
```

Be aware that you pay the shuffle price for repartitioning, so use with care.

Comment: My situation is I have more than one DStream (for parallelism) which I then union into one DStream. 

If this DStream provided me [a, b, c, d], I want to partition this out such that [a,b] is one partition and [c,d] is another.

Comment: @RanjitIyer I don't get the issue. You'd like [a,b] and [c,d] in different partitions. What do you have at the moment? As I mentioned, partitions are defined by how the messages are consumed by the receivers.So partitioning will need to happen upstream (outside Spark, using whatever primitives the stream allows)

Comment: So if two receivers produce two RDDs in the DStream [a,b,w,x] and [c,d,y,z], I want them repartitioned to have the following: [a,b,c,d] and [w,x,y,z]. I think that the code example you give above would be the way to do it.