# PartitionbyKey in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Does spark streaming have a partitionbykey functionality? I would like to partition my dstreams such that the data for the same key is in the same partition.

I.e. data for key 1 is in partition 1, and key 2 is in partition 2 etc.

Comment: Use custom partitioner. Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127329/how-to-define-custom-partitioner-for-spark-rdds-of-equally-sized-partition-where and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888165/custom-partiotioning-of-javadstreampairrdd

Comment: You mean you have multiple streams and you want Key1 from all streams to go to partition1and so on?

Comment: No i have a single dstream as of now, which i would like to partition by key... Ie all elements of an rdd belonging to key 1 in a dstream are in one partition